# How to grep number of unique occurrences

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I understand that `grep -c string` can be used to count the occurrences of a given string. What I would like to do is count the number of unique occurrences when only part of the string is known or remains constant.

For Example, if I had a file (in this case a log) with several lines containing a constant string and a repeating variable like so:

```
string=value1
string=value1
string=value1
string=value2
string=value3
string=value2
```

Than I would like to be able to identify the number of each unique set with an output similar to the following:  (ideally with a single grep/awk string)

```
value1 = 3 occurrences
value2 = 2 occurrences
value3 = 1 occurrences
```

Does anyone have a solution using grep or awk that might work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `I understand that grep -c string can be used to count the occurrences of a given string.` this is not true. it counts matching lines. e.g. you `grep -c foo <<< "foo foo foo"` will return `1`

Comment: I thought about trying something like `grep -c wwn=* <fileName>` but I'm not sure how to get the count for each unique occurrence of "www=" and/or the string itself.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This worked perfectly... Thanks to everyone for your comments!

`grep -oP "wwn=[^,]*" path/to/file | sort | uniq -c`

Comment: when I tried this out, I noticed something interesting. When I don't sort before trying to find unique occurences, `uniq` didn't seem to function properly, I got all occurences anyway. Anybody else notice it?

Comment: The `sort` command takes a list of items and sorts them alphabetically and numerically. The `uniq` command takes a list of items and removes adjacent duplicate lines. The key word being "adjacent" duplicates.. sorting the output first ensures duplicate strings are adjacent to each other for processing by the `uniq` command.

Answer (score 6):

In general, if you want to grep and also keep track of results, it is best to use `awk` since it performs such things in a clear manner with a very simple syntax.

So for your given file I would use:

```
$ awk -F= '/string=/ {count[$2]++} END {for (i in count) print i, count[i]}' file
value1 3
value2 2
value3 1
```

What is this doing?

- `-F=`
  set the field separator to `=`, so that we can compute the right and left part of it.
- `/string=/ {count[$2]++}`
  when the pattern "string=" is found, check it! This uses an array `count[]` to keep track on the times the second field has appeared so far.
- `END {for (i in count) print i, count[i]}`
  at the end, loop through the results and print them.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an awk script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    file = ARGV[1]
    while ((getline line < file) > 0) {
        for (i = 2; i < ARGC; ++i) {
            p = ARGV[i]
            if (line ~ p) {
                a[p] += !a[p, line]++
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 2; i < ARGC; ++i) {
        p = ARGV[i]
        printf("%s = %d occurrences\n", p, a[p])
    }
    exit
}
```

Example:

```
awk -f script.awk somefile ab sh
```

Output:

```
ab = 7 occurrences
sh = 2 occurrences
```